# Low performance in OrientDB simple query

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'am having a low performance in a simple query.
I have a class SimpleVertex with a field named s.
I added 1000000 vertex with the field "u"+i

When hay run this query:

select from SimpleVertex where s like 'u1000'

it took 13.001 sec to return the vertex.

if I run this query:
select from SimpleVertex where s like 'u1000%'

it took 13.214 sec to return, but the same queries running on a PostgreSQL run on 112ms and 233ms.

Why is the query so slow?

Comment: I suggest you to use a full-text (lucene) index on s if you want a quick response of that. Look at the documentation on the way to use it.

Comment: Much better, but consider this: select from SimpleVertex where s.toUppercase().normalize() like "%AO%" since I have vertex with á,é,í,ó,ú and ñ as a part of the string. It's not look so simple to implement in Lucene.

Comment: With Lucene you can define custom analyzers, so you can easily work around language specific accents and just ignore upper/lower case, see https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Full-Text-Index.html#analyzer

Comment: Well, after a lots of hours reading I could not find the correct solution. It seems like Lucene is failing when the searched expression is in the end of word. Example: "abismábamos inextinguibles parcelaríamos enchufemos " is in the ODB but 
select $score, * from SimpleVertex where s lucene "*mos" 
fail.

Comment: We have patched the SpanishAnalyzer and now work as expected so Lucene solve our problem, but the original question is still open. Why like is 118x slower than PostgreSQL like search?